# SA Admin SQL-Server 2012 x64 keeps changing constantly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, role, windows-8

I know this is a newbie question, but really I can't find some precise info on this issue.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new user with admin server role on SQL Server 2012 x64.

I mean, I do know how to do it, both graphically and through `sqlcmd`, fact is, if I create user let's say on prompt, like this:

```
1> CREATE LOGIN '<Login_Name>' with PASSWORD='<Password>'
2> GO
```

Then:

```
1> SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER '<Login_Name>','SYSADMIN'
2> GO
```

It does create the user, and adds it to srvrolemember, BUT, it keeps changing password, it never saves with the password I supply on `CREATE LOGIN`, BTW I don't remember `sa` user password either, with that user is the same story.

And I do notice, the encrypted dot length when I create new Login is the same as `sa` user, so I think it's the same password, also can't change `sa` password, it keeps the same lengthy password which I can't remember. No matter how many times I try.

I login into server with Windows Authentication.

I hope I explained myself, any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Mixed Authentication enabled for both SQL Server and Windows logins?

Comment: What do you mean "it keeps changing password"?

Comment: The user you're trying to add, is that a Windows/AD login or a SQL Server login? If it's the latter, have you verified that the server accepts SQL Server authentication and not just Windows authentication?

Comment: Password cannot change by its own. Did you used TSQL to create login can you post exact query ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, it is a SQL Server Login, going to check both, also @JohnMcCall

Comment: Yes @Shanky but not for sa user

Comment: What is your server's security settings for "Enforce password policy", "Enforce password expiration" and  "User must change password at next login"?

Comment: 'Enforce password policy'

Comment: Solved, thank you all very much for your time, I just clicked on the server instance->Properties->Security->Enable Mixed Windows-SQL authentication.